# voice chat using java with two way communication and low delay

Tags: java, chat

I want to implement a voice chat application using java , i can capture audio and playback, but i want to know how i can do this in a way that client "A" can listen when client "b" is saying something with very low delay .. 
usually in my program client "A" starts recording and when it clicks on stop recording, then client "B" can listen.
I don't want anyone to write code for me, I just need guidance ..

what i have done

`get input#
stop recording#
send it to other client#
that client can now listen audio`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you capture and send the audio data directly, without waiting for 'stop recording'?
Always when you have new Data, send it (or have a treshold on packet size).
On the other side, play that new audio data but also (from another Thread) record and send own data. You might use a Socket for data transfer. Of course you would need some low level access on the audio input...

You might wan't to have a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CapturingAudiowithJavaSoundAPI.htm) snippet.

Comment: actually I am converting audio data to bit Array and then sending it to remote client and then the remote client it converting it back to audio ..  but can u enplane how I can send audio directly?